# How could I make my program play sounds according to a key.is_pressed statement?

Tags: python

Consider:

```
from playsound import playsound
import keyboard

notes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
while True:
    x = keyboard.is_pressed('')
    try:
        if x = (1):
            playsound('thingthing.wav')
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

I'm trying to make a basic synthesizer that plays basic notes, but the problem is I don’t want to use *if else* statements way too much, so I decided on using a list. But how could I trigger events using lists?

I want to make a basic synthesizer that works on lists.

```
from playsound import playsound
import keyboard
notes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
        playsound('a.wav')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
        playsound('b.wav')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('3'):
        playsound('c.wav')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('4'):
        playsound('d.wav')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('5'):
        playsound('e.wav')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('6'):
        playsound('f.wav')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('7'):
        playsound('g.wav')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('8'):
        pass
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('9'):
        pass
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('0'):
        pass
    else:
        pass
    if keyboard.is_pressed('num_1'):
        break
    else:
        pass
```

This is the final code, but I am not happy with it.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your program is supposed to do. Where does `notes` come into play?

Comment: Also, there's a syntax error in the line `if x = (1):`, did you mean `if x == 1:` (or just `if x:`)?

Comment: @timgeb notes[] were supposed to be a list, i thought i would be able to reach the final result as i did in the code i just added, basically i didnt want to use if's so i tried using lists instead and i failed

Comment: Why are you not happy with it?

Comment: In English, the subjective form of the singular first-person pronoun, "I", is capitalized, along with all its contractions such as I'll and I'm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dictionary that maps keys to sounds.

```
key_to_sound = {
    '1': 'a.wav',
    '2': 'b.wav',
    ...
}
```

Then your loop can be written as

```
while True:
    key = keyboard.read_key()

    if key == 'num_1':
        break
    elif key in key_to_sound:
        playsound(key_to_sound[key])
```

Comment: yeah that was pretty much what i was trying to accomplish, didnt know there was a read statement in the keyboard module, helped much thänks

Answer (score 1):

```
import winsound
import keyboard
alias = winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_NODEFAULT
while True:
    y = keyboard.read_key()
    d = "pykeyboardfeedback\\" + y + '.wav'
    winsound.PlaySound(d, alias)
```

It turns out the problem I had was to concentrate way too much on catching an exception and implementing stuff that are both difficult and useless, like the dict there.

It adds y to the folder name and then adds a .wav at the end, so we use it there.